# Combining SpringBoot, Zuul and Eureka but bind Services to Localhost

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix

I have set up Zuul for routing and Eureka for service discovery, which works fine. Before setting up Eureka, I used `server.address=127.0.0.1` to bind my actual service to `localhost` so that they could only be accessed from within the Api gateway.

When combining Zuul and Eureka, `server.address=127.0.0.1` does not work anymore. I cannot access my actual REST endpoints, neither from within my network nor from the outside.

**application.properties of my Eureka service discovery:**

```
spring.application.name=service-discovery
server.port=8761
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
```

**application.properties of my Zuul API gateway:**

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
zuul.prefix=/api
server.port=8080

ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

zuul.routes.library.path=/library/**
zuul.routes.library.serviceId=library
```

**application.properties of my actual REST service:**

```
spring.application.name=library
server.servlet.context-path=/library
server.port=8090
server.address=127.0.0.1

ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

When I remove `server.address=127.0.0.1` from the REST service's properties file, I can of course access the resource - But also from without `localhost`, which is not what I want.

So what I try to achieve is that my little microservices can only be accessed from within `localhost` (after the request has passed the Zuul API gateway). Furthermore I want to use Eureka for service discovery and for having the chance to provide second instances of serives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering the actual microservices with `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost` or `eureka.instance.ip-address=127.0.0.1` to the Eureka server, combined with a binding of the microservice to localhost (`server.address=127.0.0.1`) did the job.

These are the application.properties files:

**application.properties of my Eureka service discovery:**

```
spring.application.name=service-discovery
server.port=8761
server.address=127.0.0.1
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
```

**application.properties of my Zuul API gateway:**

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
zuul.prefix=/api
server.port=8080
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
zuul.routes.library.path=/library/**
zuul.routes.library.serviceId=library
zuul.routes.library.stripPrefix=false
```

**application.properties of my actual REST service:**

```
spring.application.name=library
server.servlet.context-path=/library
server.port=8090
server.address=127.0.0.1
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.ip-address=127.0.0.1
```

The "library" microservice is now only available from localhost but still registered at Eureka and behind the Zuul API gateway.